# Splash screen issue regarding order of load

Tags: android, flutter, dart, splash-screen

https://www.kapwing.com/w/cjvGksf9q9

screen recording for the splash screen want to make this splash screen load in a smoother fashion overall specially make the animation load first then the text also give tips on the design aspect of the splash screen if you guys feel like

```
enter code here

import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:yoga_2/screen.dart';

class MySplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'splash';
  const MySplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySplashScreen> createState() => _MySplashScreenState();
}

class _MySplashScreenState extends State<MySplashScreen> {
  startTimer() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), () async {
      

      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => const Screen()));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    startTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
            child: Lottie.network(
                "https://lottie.host/1bc0c8f3-8fe7-4535-993f-d03d0741257e/x5uDIJJBVj.json"),
          ),
          Center(
              child:
                  AnimatedTextKit(animatedTexts: [FadeAnimatedText('Dhāraṇā')]))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you load the Lottie file from assets instead of loading it from the network?